# Верно ли составлено первое предложение? Верно ли стоит тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Крем-суп из брокколи, тыквенный с пряностями, грибной, морковный, холодный гаспачо с шариком творожного сыра - необычная подача с палочкой гриссини или лингетте. Эффектная замена привычному хлебу. Превратите любой обед в праздничный.

Comment: Тире - нормально, а в чем затруднение-то с первым предложением? Если вопрос только в тире, то тут и думать нечего.

Comment: Спасибо! Поспорили с редактором, счел, что тут тире практически тоже самое, что и равно. Супы не могут быть подачей. Нарушение логического построения фразы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

Крем-суп из брокколи, тыквенный с пряностями, грибной, морковный, холодный гаспачо с шариком творожного сыра. И необычная подача с палочкой гриссини или лингетте - эффектная замена привычному хлебу. Превратите любой обед в праздничный.

В предлагаемом варианте не очень логичная  разбивка текста по темам.

Answer (score 1):

> Спасибо! Поспорили с редактором, счел, что тут тире практически то же самое, что и равно. Супы не могут быть подачей. Нарушение логического построения фразы.

Вообще-то он прав в том, что "суп" не равен "подаче". Но неправ, думаю, в подходе к тире. Тут перечисление с опущенным родовым (или собирательным) словом "всё" или "супы". И даже если бы это относилось к одному последнему супу, для тире была бы иная мотивация, чем просто "равно супу". Не супу, а супу с каким-то там декоративным элементом. А это уже есть именно оформление, т. е. "подача".

Вообще у кулинаров помимо "подачи" есть какой-то термин, которым они обозначают вот эту самую штуку, оформление и гарнитуру при отпуске блюда, *композиция*, что ли. Вот поставьте вместо "подачи" эту самую "композицию" - ну неужели редактор и тут придерется?! А "подача" почти синоним этой композиции.

Но с другой стороны, я люблю отвечать именно на вопросы, поставленные ребром, поэтому и рассуждаю. А вон там уже давно вариант редактирования предложили. Если Вы готовы что-то менять в тексте, кроме знаков, то лучше, конечно, поменять - потому как стилистические шероховатости все-таки есть: вторая фраза куцая какая-то, не поймешь, что это за замена такая. Да и третья без восклицательного знака выглядит скорее как просьба.

Comment: *Да и третья без восклицательного знака выглядит скорее как просьба.* +100!